# Apache Camel Kafka support for Confluent schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to create camel route with kafka component trying to consume events with `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer` and schemaRegistry url along with other component parameters. I am not sure if this is full supported by Camel-Kafka currently. Can someone please comment on this ?

```
from("kafka:{{kafka.notification.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.notification.brokers}}"
                + "&maxPollRecords={{kafka.notification.maxPollRecords}}"
                + "&seekTo={{kafka.notification.seekTo}}"
                + "&specificAvroReader=" + "true"
                + "&valueDeserializer=" + "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
                +"&schemaRegistryURL=localhost:9021"
                + "&allowManualCommit={{kafka.notification.autocommit}})
```

`specificAvroReader` & `schemaRegistryURL` are the properties which seems to be not supported.

Comment: Refered https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc. Seems like this is supposed to be a part of Camel 3.0.0-M2 release.But  i dont see it in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-kafka or  https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/camel/apache-camel/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use camel-avro-consumer & producer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190052/how-to-use-camel-avro-consumer-producer)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way currently to have camel-kafka to work with Confluent Schema Registry is to write a custom AvroSerilizer/ AvroDeserializer (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer/ io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer). E.g.:

```
BlablaDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object>
```

and

```
BlablaSerializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer implements Serializer<Object>
```

and then set them on the camel component. E.g. for the value it will be:

```
 KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration.setValueDeserializer(...)
```

Comment: i;m replying really very late, but it might help someone. yes you are right! and i have written customavro serilizer and deserializer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190052/how-to-use-camel-avro-consumer-producer/55234351#55234351

Answer (score 1):

Got this working after adding this to Gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-kafka:3.0.0-M2'
```

which can be found in this staging repository https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachecamel-1124/org/apache/camel/

I think 3.0.0-M2 will be officially supported by Camel early next week.

Edit : 3.0.0-M2  available now https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/camel/apache-camel/3.0.0-M2/

Has support for camel Kafka & Confluent Schema registry

Comment: one of the links above doesn't work https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachecamel-1124/org/apache/camel/. @cricket_007 directed me here but i couldn't see a solution. i had the exact same question but stackoverflow dint return me your page earlier. I have solved it a month ago now. if you did have a different solution, i would have loved to see without downloading the zip and taking that exercise

Comment: Is there a working example somewhere? I am losing my mind on this isssue

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, this has been solved in the meantime. You do not have to write your own serializer/deserializer.

I made full example with camel-quarkus and schema-registry from confluent:
https://github.com/tstuber/camel-quarkus-kafka-schema-registry